# Description of all the complex roots

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there a nice way to describe all the set of values that the expression
$\frac{1}{(-i)^{d/2}\,(i)^{d/2}}$ can take? $d$ is assumed to be a real parameter while $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary number. I am not entirely sure which simplification operations are allowed.

Comment: When in doubt, use the definition $a^b=e^{b\log(a)}$. For example, $i^{d/2}=e^{(d/2)\log(i)}=e^{(d/2)\log(e^{i\pi})}=e^{(d/2)(i\pi + 2k\pi i)}=e^{(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2} d i}$, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: And yes, do not use something like $a^cb^c=(ab)^c$, which is not true in general.

Comment: @NDB So, is it correct that the final expression is $e^{k\pi di}$?

Comment: I haven't computed it. By the way, I missed an $/2$ above, when replacing $i$ by $e^{i\pi}$. It should be $e^{i\pi/2}$.

Comment: @NDB I mean, the only thing that I need to ask is if the factor $(-i)^{d/2}$ involves the same $k$ or a different one?

Comment: That belongs to the area of conventions, whatever the person who wrote the expression intended. Unless said otherwise, one would expect that the same branch of the logarithm is used everywhere.

Comment: @NDB let us say that there is no such a person and I have to figure out if to use the same branch or not. Is there any way that allow me to decide if I'm allowed to ignore the other branches?